# java- why is my "deposit" method not working for my ATM with gui?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm making an ATM in which the user must first enter their pin (1234), and then once the pin is entered correctly, the user can either withdraw 50, 100, or 200 dollars or make a deposit under $1000. My withdraw methods are all working, but when I run my program and try to make any deposit, nothing happens after I enter the amount and try to hit the "enter" button. It seems as if my enter button is not working. Here is the code used for my deposit method:

```
 if (event.getSource() == deposit) {
    instructionScreen.setText("Enter the amount you would like to deposit, then click Enter.");

    if (event.getSource() == enter) {
       saveScreen = displayInput.getText();
       double add = Double.parseDouble(saveScreen);
       if (add <= 1000) {
          balance += add;
          instructionScreen.setText("Your new balance is $" + balance + ".");
       }
       else {
          instructionScreen.setText("The maximum amount you can deposit is $1000. Please enter a new amount.");
          displayInput.setText("");
          if (event.getSource() == enter) {
             saveScreen = displayInput.getText();
             add = Double.parseDouble(saveScreen);
          }
       }

       displayInput.setText("");
       System.out.println("A deposit of $" + add + "was made. Your new balance is $" + balance);
    }
 }
```

What is wrong with the code that is causing my deposit not to do anything when I hit enter after entering an amount to deposit?

Answer (score 2):

Your program would work great if it were a linear console program, but this is not how event-driven programming works. Instead of expecting the source to change immediately and magically from deposit to enter, you need to change the state of the object if deposit is selected, perhaps by changing a boolean field, and then testing that field in the enter's action listener.

e.g.,

```
if (event.getSource() == deposit) {
    instructionScreen.setText("Enter the amount you would like to deposit, then click Enter.");
    depositState = true;  // a boolean field
} else if (event.getSource() == enter) {
    if (depositState) {
        depositState = false; // reset it

        saveScreen = displayInput.getText();
        double add = Double.parseDouble(saveScreen);
        // .... etc
```